# WordPress mobile detect / bootstrap grid

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-design

On my web page I need to render different code for mobile, tablet and desktop users, because in an php if statement I need to pass a different `$i` value.
For mobile, it is a simple case because I'm using the `wp_is_mobile` function. But how can I pass different parts of PHP code to bootstrap `col-sm-` and `col-md-` breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to. We have different breakpoints for different screen sizes.

As an example:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
```

The above code will render the div differently, and automatically.

- Medium screens have 2 columns of width 6.
- Small screens have one column spanning the screen width
- Large screens have 3 columns of
  width 4

Comment: You are right if it goes for css, but in php I have a query with an if statement witch determines how many post is creating a row in accordion tabs. And for `col-` 1 post creates a row (I got this working with wp_is_mobile), and for `.col-xl-` 4 post are creating a row. I would also like to have control over the other breakpoints.

Comment: get the screensize with javascript and load the php with ajax